# MSSQL: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculation MTTR.This is formula **Sum(Finish_Date-Start_Date)/n**  I need to calculate in SQL Server.

```
SELECT dbo.BOYS.Machine_ID,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, Start_Date, Finish_Date)) as Total_TTR
    , SUM(1) AS n
    , SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, Start_Date, Finish_Date))/SUM(1) AS MTTR
FROM [BT].[dbo].[BOYS]
GROUP BY Machine_ID
```

I calculate it second type.

- MTTR
- 3600
- 165600
- ...

in table.
but I want it in **hh:mm:ss** format.

- MTTR
- 01:25:13 etc.
- ...

I use

```
SELECT dbo.BOYS.Machine_ID,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, First_Date, Second_Date)) as Total_DT
    ,SUM(1) AS n, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, First_Date, Second_Date))/SUM(1) AS MDT
    , Convert(varchar(6), ((SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, First_Date, Second_Date))/SUM(1))/3600)
    + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, First_Date, Second_Date)/SUM(1)) % 3600) / 60), 2)
    + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, First_Date, Second_Date))/SUM(1)) %60),2)) AS 'MTTR'
 FROM [BT].[dbo].[BOYS]
 GROUP BY Machine_ID
```

but it throws an error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: You could put the original query in a subquery, and then you can query from there and do what you want without having to deal with any aggregate

Comment: Sorry..Could you give me example? I am not good at sql.

Comment: Have you considered using the `TIMEFROMPARTS` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the query with the group by in a subquery, and then select on that resultset, then you don't have to worry about aggregates in the upper select.

Look at this example

first I need to create some sample data

```
declare @boys table (machine_id int, start_Date datetime, finish_Date datetime)

insert into @boys values 
  (1, '20220728 08:00:00', '20220728 09:15:30'),
  (1, '20220728 10:30:00', '20220728 10:45:00'),
  (2, '20220728 08:30:00', '20220728 14:12:31')
```

now for the query, it was not clear to me if you want to build the time for the average or for the total, so I put both in the query, just pick the one you need

```
select t.Machine_ID,
       t.n,
       t.Total_DT,
       t.MDT,
       
       -- time base on the average
       Convert( varchar(6), (MDT / 3600))
                + ':'
                + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (MDT % 3600) / 60), 2)
                + ':'
                + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (MDT % 60)), 2)
       as MTTR_avg,
       
       -- time base on the total
       Convert( varchar(6), (Total_DT / 3600))
                + ':'
                + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (Total_DT % 3600) / 60), 2)
                + ':'
                + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (Total_DT % 60)), 2)
       as MTTR_tot
                
from   ( SELECT b.Machine_ID,
                SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, b.Start_Date, b.Finish_Date)) as Total_DT,
                SUM(1) AS n, 
                SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, b.Start_Date, b.Finish_Date)) / SUM(1) AS MDT
         FROM   @boys b 
         group by Machine_ID
       ) t
```

It also makes the convert much more easy to read.

It results in this

| Machine_ID | n | Total_DT | MDT | MTTR_avg | MTTR_tot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5430 | 2715 | 0:45:15 | 1:30:30 |
| 2 | 1 | 20551 | 20551 | 5:42:31 | 5:42:31 |

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue is this line, with spacing you can see the issue is a bracket in the wrong place, so you have `SUM(1)` inside the other `SUM`.

```sql
RIGHT(
  '0' +
  CONVERT(
    varchar(2),
    (
      SUM(
        DATEDIFF(
          SECOND,
          First_Date, 
          Second_Date
        )
        / SUM(1)
      )
      % 3600
    )
    / 60
  ),
  2
)
```

You can clean this up considerably.

- Firstly, put the `DATEDIFF` in a `CROSS APPLY(VALUES` so you don't have to repeat it.
- `SUM(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`, and `SUM(x) / COUNT(*)` is the same as `AVG(x)`.
- Use `TIMEFROMPARTS` to create a time value.
- Don't use three-part naming. Your connection should define which database you are using.
- Don't quote table and column names unless you have to. And if you do, do it with `[]`.

```sql
SELECT
      b.Machine_ID
    , SUM(v.diff) AS Total_DT
    , COUNT(*) AS n
    , AVG(v.diff) AS MDT
    , TIMEFROMPARTS(
        AVG(v.diff) / 3600,
        (AVG(v.diff) % 3600) / 60,
        AVG(v.diff) % 60,
        0, 0) AS MTTR
FROM dbo.BOYS b
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, b.First_Date, b.Second_Date)
) ) v(diff)
GROUP BY
  b.Machine_ID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0310a31a9bda28688f26cfc4893973a0)

Comment: Are you sure the value of MTTR is correct in your dbfiddle for the first row ?

Comment: is not the total time for machine 1 1 hour, 30 minutes and 30 seconds in stead of 0 hours, 45 minutes and 15 seconds ?

Comment: Correct, that's column `Total_DT`. But the `MTTR` looks like it's supposed to be the average, like `MDT`

Comment: I guess I misunderstood that then